# Why is locationManager (:didUpdateLocations) not called

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I wrote following test code

```
 @IBAction func btnLocation(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let locManager = CLLocationManager()
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != .authorized {
        print("not authorized")
    }
    locManager.delegate = self
    locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locManager.requestLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[0]
    print(location.coordinate.latitude)
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(places, error) in
        let place: CLPlacemark = places![0]
        print(place.administrativeArea!)
    })
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("authorization changed")
}
```

but `locationManager(:didUpdateLocations)` is not called and no error is printed. If I remove `locationManager(:didFailWithError)` method than in start works and location coordinate is printed but Xcode also claims that "Delegate must respond to `locationManager:didFailWithError:`
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make

```
let locManager = CLLocationManager()
```

an instance var to hold a strong reference for the delegate , also you either need 1 of these

```
locManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locManager.requestLocation()
```

Comment: Thanks. I made let locManager = CLLocationManager() declaration on class level and it works fine now.